# IEnumerable<string> to Stream for FileStreamResult

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, stream, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable<string>`, which is "streamed" per `yield` statements from a method. Now I want to convert this enumerable to a `Stream` to use it as streamed result. Any ideas how I can do this?

What I finally want to do is to return the `Stream` as `FileStreamResult` from an ASP.NET controller action. This result should be streamed as download to the client.

What I do NOT want to do is to write the whole content of the `IEnumerable` to the stream before I return the result. This would eliminate the whole sense of the streaming concept.

Comment: Why do you want to use a `FileStreamResult`, specifically? Wouldn't it make sense to write your own `ActionResult` that specifies content-type / content-disposition, and behaves as you want? Note: one problem you might want to think about is : how to set the content-length header ahead of time, without iterating and encoding the data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to create your ActionResult class to achieve lazy evaluation. You have create mix of `ContentResult` an `FileStreamResult` classes to achieve behaviour like FileStreamResult with ability to set result encoding.  Good starting point is `FileResult` abstract class:

```
public class EnumerableStreamResult : FileResult
{

    public IEnumerable<string> Enumerable
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Encoding ContentEncoding
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public EnumerableStreamResult(IEnumerable<string> enumerable, string contentType)
        : base(contentType)
    {
        if (enumerable == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");
        }
        this.Enumerable = enumerable;
    }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
        if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (this.Enumerable != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Enumerable)
            {

                //do your stuff here
                response.Write(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I was looking for! I added a `response.Flush()` to the `WriteFile` method after n enumerable entries have been written... and added some bugfixing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Matthias - "and added some bugfixing". I am writing something similar now and the above example works for me. I'd be interested to know what bug fixing you did so I don't hit the same issues.

Comment: @AndyNichols In WriteFile() I make a response.Flush() at first. Additionally, I included a block by block Flush() in the foreach loop. Otherwise the download dialog will not update its progress and the UI is blocked (in my case).

Answer (score 1):

Return a FileStreamResult, passing in enumerable.ToStream():

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    IEnumerable<string> lines = GetLines();
    Stream stream = lines.ToStream();
    return File(stream, "text/csv");
}
```

ToStream() is implemented in the [EnumerableToStream](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnumerableToStream/) package.

Answer (score -3):

I think you can use it in this first convert your string to byte array and use memory stram afterwards

```
string sourceFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("/", "yourAddress"));
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFile);

MemoryStream mem;
        using (mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
            return mem;
        }
```

Comment: Why not using `using (var mem = new MemoryStream())` instead of `using (mem = new MemoryStream())`? You can remove `MemoryStream mem;` now.

Comment: From my question: "What I do NOT want to do is to write the whole content of the IEnumerable to the stream before I return the result. This would eliminate the whole sense of the streaming concept."