# Send pieces of body as long as a IEnumerable<string> returns new string pieces in HttpRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ienumerable

Is there any out-of-the-box way in AspNetCore 2 to return result from a enumeration as long as the enumeration is iterated (usefull for keeping memory usage low, but also to print intermediate results in long-running Http requests).

Actually the "simplest" way to do that is returning a file stream and using a class for [converting a IEnumerable to Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830393/ienumerablestring-to-stream-for-filestreamresult), which is far from being a very simple solution. I feel there's a simpler solution that I can't get due to my lack of experience with AspNetCore 2.0

What I want to achieve is configuring AspNetCore to send pieces of body while the HTTP request is running as long as the total string output reach the "Configured Content-Lenght". After that it stops sending pieces of strings and continue to compute until the computation is ended.

In that way a client that shows strings as long as they are received can act as a sort of "logging mechanism".

Comment: Not related to ASP.NET Core at all, just language specific feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Comment: `IEnumerable<>` only returns results when requested, so what you want is 1) the very definition of `IEnumerable<T>` and 2) useless for *web applications*. A web applications generates HTML. When you generate that HTML the IEnumerable or Stream will be enumerated fully. If you want a different behaviour you'll have to pull data from the client, ie the browser, using Javascript. Or use a push mechanism like web sockets to push data to the client

Comment: The "simplest" way looks simple though...

Comment: @UberFace what is your *actual* question? What are you trying to do? How much data do you want to display? Or is the actual question `print intermediate results in long-running Http requests`? HTTP itself doesn't allow intermediate results. That's what SignalR and WebSockets are about

Comment: @UberFace you are probably asking two completely different things: a) how to load and display data as needed, which can be done by using an API with paging, virtualized scrolling in your UI, AJAX calls, fetch etc. That's primarily a *Javascript* question Or b) send notifications to clients. That's what [ASP.NET SingalR Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1) provides

Comment: I want to stream response body as long as there is a new message to be displayed. The client already handles partial bodies. Not sure if I can implement that in AspNetCore though

Comment: @UberFace impossible with HTTP, no matter the server or language. Why do you want that? What is the *actual* question to which you thought `stream as long as there is a new message` would be the answer?

Comment: @UberFace in fact `The client already handles partial bodies` is an illusion. The *client* may be reading whatever the server sends byte by byte from the stream and process it in batches. That doesn't mean that the server knows *anything* about the client though, it just sends data. If the client stopped abruptly the server would still send data until the TCP connection closed.

Comment: oh, forgot about content lenght header.. so it is not possible in anyway :(? (neither setting up a big body lenght and filling the lenght with 0s if the IEnumerable finish enumerating) So the client is actually broken I guess

Comment: @UberFace what isn't possible? You still didn't ask the actual question. I'd bet the answer to the *actual* question is "Yes, lots of sites do that already". Just not by keeping a stream open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net Core 1.1 chunked responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722936/asp-net-core-1-1-chunked-responses)

Comment: @PeterB not a good duplicate. SSE is just one of the [transport mechanisms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1#transports) used by SignalR and it's not about chunked responses anyway.

Comment: @UberFace you could use for example WebSockets or SignalR to send the actual results as notifications. A more conventional solution would be to create an HTTP API that allows paging

Comment: Take some time to familiarize yourself with the HTTP and underlying IP protocols. Just as you wouldn't expect to be able to build an iOS app without understanding how iOS works, you should have an understanding of the web as a platform if you intend to build web applications. Long and short, this isn't possible for a number of reasons, including the core way these protocols function.